# How to upload pdf to server using retrofit

Tags: java, android, pdf, retrofit, retrofit2

I am unable to upload pdf through properly but when i upload pdf from postman that its working fine.When i upload pdf from my app that its upload but corrpt file I am using these code

```
   Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   chooseFile.setType("application/pdf");
   chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a 
   file");
   startActivityForResult(chooseFile, 1212);

            


    Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file://" + selectedDocPath);
    File file = new File(uri1.getPath());
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), 
    file.getAbsolutePath());
    multipartBody[0] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), 
    requestFile);
```

I am getting the path in **onActivityResult** method like this

```
 Uri uri = data.getData();
 selectedDocPath = getPath(uri);
```

Comment: `File file = new File(uri1.getPath());` Please tell the value of `uri1.getPath()`. Also tell the value of `uri1.toString()`.

Comment: `selectedDocPath = getPath(uri);` Please tell the value of `selectedDocPath`.

Comment: @blackapps selectedDocPath =/storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy (1).pdf
uri1.getPath =file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy (1).pdf
file= /storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy (1).pdf

Comment: @blackapps selectedDocPath =/storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy (1).pdf
uri1.getPath =file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy (1).pdf
file= /storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy (1).pdf

Comment: `Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file://" + selectedDocPath);
    File file = new File(uri1.getPath());` That is nonsense code. Please think again.

Comment: And what is the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` ?

Comment: file.getAbsolutePath()=/share/Download/dummy.pdf

what about if i use         Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", new File(selectedDocPath));
 To get uri

Comment: Well that is not a valid path. How is it possible? As the other paths you mentioned look ok.

Comment: @blackapps sorry i sent you wrong  this is the value  /storage/emulated/0/Download/dummy (1).pdf of file.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: `pdf from my app that its upload but corrpt file I` How is it corrupt? Please tell better what the server received. What is file size (in bytes) or original and uploaded file? Which Android version on device used?

Comment: @blackapps my original file is 13.26 KB and server recieved upto 3 MB
and if i upload that file from postman than its uploading fine not corrpt

Comment: Mmmm... interesting. I think you should read some stackoverflow pages tagged `retrofit` as what you want is pretty standard (and has been asked before). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retrofit Put a `retrofit` tag on your post too.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the your time where are you from?

Comment: `Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.` ;-).

Comment: http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/06/android-upload-image-file-using-retrofit-2-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Ion** Library to upload the PDF,Images and Video.Its very easy and not too complex try once

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should get file by ContentProvider, if your app targets Android N.
see [android-7.0-changes?authuser=1#sharing-files](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes?authuser=1#sharing-files)

Comment: @lvan J.Lee How I can get file by ContentProvider?